# How to save or move image files from application to general media folder

Tags: android

I currently have an application that will take a picture upon button click. However the photos are being stored under the application directory in a "Pictures" folder. How do you save or copy the images to the general DCIM folder that can be viewed in the general Android Photos Gallery.

An example would be great!

**Location in MainActivity.java where I specify directory**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{

        //Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, //prefix
                ".jpg", //suffix
                storageDir //directory
        );

        //Save a file: path 
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Prior to Android 10, you could either configure `FileProvider` and your Java code to store the images there directly, or use standard Java file I/O to copy from the current location to one in `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`. On Android 10+, you will need to use a `ContentResolver` to `insert()` metadata about your photo to a `MediaStore.Images` `Uri`. `insert()` will return a `Uri` that you can then use with `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream`, which you can use to copy over the bytes of the photo.

Comment: Thanks, I am not too familiar with `ContentResolver`. Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) saves videos instead of images (and is in Kotlin instead of Java), but otherwise shows how to save content on both Android 10+ and older devices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, String imageName,Context mContext,String description) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

        //adding images to Media Gallery using MediaStore
        try {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), filePath, imageName, description);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("Error","error in inserting image");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then to call it:

```
addImageToGallery(filepath,imageName,this,description);
```

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage is deprecated, any other alternative ?